# Integrating Kafka and sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, queue, apache-kafka, service-broker

I have a SQL 2008 R2 database that i would like to integrate with Kafka 
so essentially I want to use Change data capture to capture changes in my table and put them on a Kafka Queue - this is for the front end Devs to read the data off Kafka. Has anyone done this before or have any tips on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can do it directly from Sql server. You have to write your own producer that will pull day from Sql, and push to Kafka queue. We are currently doing the same thing via background services that pushed data to Kafka

Answer (score 2):

[Kafka Connectors](http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors) will solve this problem now in particular the JDBC connector.

> The JDBC connector allows you to import data from any relational
>   database with a JDBC driver into Kafka topics. By using JDBC, this
>   connector can support a wide variety of databases without requiring
>   custom code for each one.

Source: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/jdbc_connector.html

See also:

[Kafka Connect JDBC Connector source code on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc)

[Kafka Connect Documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#connect)

Comment: Thanks alot for this - will give it a go